# custom iphone tab bar area

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller

I want to create a custom tab bar for an iphone app that looks like this image:

[image: Custom Tab Image]

there would be multiple clickable semi-circles at the top that would switch tabs.  Each tab would have some buttons or other UI items under the semi-circles that allow you to interact with the display at the top.

It seems that the iphone tab bar controller is only for a certain fixed look.  Can I reuse those classes to do what I need?  Any good examples of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this by using a custom tab view controller that inherits from UIViewController.  I used layered UIImageViews and hid them based on UIButtons the user pressed for a given tab.